# I am trying to torrent and install games

Tags: games, bittorrent

I am trying to download torrents like I did before I switched to Ubuntu. but I forgot to take into account I am not using windows OS. Is there a way to install these games even tho they are for windows? or if not, where can I find torrents made for Linux?

Comment: You can check and see if there are Linux ports of these games. If not, you will have to use WINE or dual-boot Windows with Ubuntu or use a VM (but this is likely to be slow depending on the games).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games aren't programed for Linux, [save for a few](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=&sort_by=_ASC&os=linux&page=1).

If you are asking how to play Windows games in Linux then install either [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/), PlayOnLinux, or Crossover Linux (the last one you have to pay for, so I just use Wine).

If you are asking how to torrent in Ubuntu, then you can use the Bittorrent app that comes with Ubuntu: Transmission.

If you are asking where to find torrents for Linux, you can try here: [Torrentz2](https://torrentz2.eu/).

Hope this helps :)